# Windows 10: Taskbar has gap at the bottom that shows desktop

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop

I recently started using a wallpaper again, after using just a black color for my wall paper for a long time and noticed that there is a gap at the bottom that shows my desktop.

[image]

If I increase my taskbar's height then it just cuts off/stops showing the icons, start menu, and time date etc. and just shows even more.

[image]

If I right click it on the desktop space below it just, shows typical right click on desktop options.

Can anyone help?

Comment: thanks for your response john, I checked my startup items and something similar to what you described was there. I turned it off and restarted and everything was good again.

Comment: Great to know - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your taskbar is floating and that is not a native feature to Windows (10).

You may have installed Star Dock or some like tool that adds "features" to the taskbar and start button.

Star Dock is a third party product and has an ObjectDock accessory as well.

Remove or adjust the third party software.